# How to verify day and time using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

i have added piece of code.my concern assume my booking page contains date picker and ime picker with one submit button .if user selecred some date and time he/she submit the page after submit i need to verify user selected day and time whether match with shop open day and time .
i have written some piece of code after submit i call that function but i don't know whether its right or not pls some one help me out.
below i given two example assume that example selected by user pls solve that examples

After user submission we need to verify with this data. i have added code below
 $scope.dealers = [{

```
   S_Email_id: "aditiya@gmail.com",
    S_Store: "samsung",
    status:"",
    Store_Name: "Adtiya Samsung Store",
    S_Services: "Regular Service,Software Faults,Hardware Faults",
    Store_long_description: "Undertake all kind of samsung mobiles",
    Store_short_description: "Undertake all kind of samsung mobiles",
  Day: {
    "monday": "09:10AM - 06:30PM",
    "tuesday": "09:10AM - 12:00PM",
    "wednesday": "09:10AM - 06:30PM",
    "thursday": "09:10AM - 06:30PM",
    "friday": "09:10AM - 06:30PM",
    "saturday": "10:15AM - 04:15PM",
    "sunday": "10:15AM - 04:15PM"
  },
},]
```

For example. 1.if i user selected  date(Wed Dec 02 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)) which means 02/12/2015  / Wednesday, and if user selected time  11:00am i need to check with shop day(which is mentioned above).selected  date(Wed Dec 02 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)) which means 02/12/2015  / Wednesday and time 11.00am match between shop open and close time so i need to show alert shop is opened .

2.if user selected  date(Thu Dec 03 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)) which means  03/12/2015/ Thursday,and if user selected time 08:00pm i need to check with shop day(which is mentioned above).selected  date(Thu Dec 03 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)) which means  03/12/2015/ Thursday and selected time 08:00pm does not match between shop open and close time so i need to show alert shop is closed or leave

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller("myCntrl", function($scope, $filter) {

    $scope.isOpen = function(dealerSchedule) {
 console.log(dealerSchedule);
      
   var udate='Wed Dec 02 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)';
   var now = new Date(udate);
   console.log(now);
   var times = dealerSchedule[Object.keys(dealerSchedule)[now.getDay() - 1]].replace(/(\d\d\:\d\d)(AM|PM)/g, '1/1/1900 $1 $2').split(" - ");
     
   //var nowTime = new Date('1/1/1900 ' + now.toLocaleTimeString(navigator.language, {
        //hour: '2-digit',
        //minute: '2-digit',
        //hour12: true
      //}));
   var ntime ='11:00am';
   var nowTime = new Date(ntime);
   console.log(nowTime);
      var response = (times == "Leave" ? "Leave" : (nowTime >= new Date(times[0]) && nowTime <= new Date(times[1]) ? "Open Now" : "Closed Now"));
     
   if(response =='Closed Now' || response =='Leave' )
   {
   alert('sorry shop closed');
   }else
   {
   alert('shop opened now');
   }
   
   
    };

 
    $scope.dealers = [{

       S_Email_id: "aditiya@gmail.com",
        S_Store: "samsung",
        status:"",
        Store_Name: "Adtiya Samsung Store",
        S_Services: "Regular Service,Software Faults,Hardware Faults",
        Store_long_description: "Undertake all kind of samsung mobiles",
        Store_short_description: "Undertake all kind of samsung mobiles",
      Day: {
        "monday": "09:10AM - 06:30PM",
        "tuesday": "09:10AM - 12:00PM",
        "wednesday": "09:10AM - 06:30PM",
        "thursday": "09:10AM - 06:30PM",
        "friday": "09:10AM - 06:30PM",
        "saturday": "10:15AM - 04:15PM",
        "sunday": "10:15AM - 04:15PM"
      },
    },  ]
    //var date = new Date();

    //$scope.hhmmsstt = $filter('date')(new Date(), 'hh:mm:ss a');
    //console.log($scope.hhmmsstt);
  })
//]]>
```

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.1.1/angular.min.js'></script>
  
  
  
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myCntrl">
    <label>Search on Label</label>
    <br>
  
    <br>
    <br>

    <div ng-repeat="dealer in dealers">

      {{dealer.Store_Name}}
      <br>{{dealer.S_Email_id}}
      <br>{{dealer.Day}}
      <br>
      <input type="button" value="order" ng-click="isOpen(dealer.Day)"/>
          
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rpbn6u23/40/)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-between/) api it will make your life a lot easier.

They have a method called `.isBetween()`.

If you did not want to use that I would create Date() objects and call .getTime() on them with will return an integer.  Then you can do some simple boolean logic with all the values.

Also, you will need to know the timezone of each of the stores in order to effectively calculate the time.

`new Date().getTimezoneOffset()` will help you get the timezone offset in minutes.

Comment: can you pls add jsfiddle for me.actually i am new to technology

Comment: In the spirit of learning, create a jsFiddle the way you think it should work.  I will lend a hand to resolve any difficulties you encounter.

Comment: i have tried last 3days i fully disappointed thats why i am asking sry

Answer (score 0):

Date cannot parse the ntime string.

```
var ntime ='11:00am';

var nowTime = new Date(ntime); //Not valid Date
```

[MDN page On Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) has all you need.
When constructing a date you will need to set each parameter like:

```
var selectedHour = 11; //24hr rules
var selectedminutes = 0;

var selectedDate = new Date(now.year, now.month, selectedHour, selectedMinutes);
```

As for checking the times the shop is open you will need to convert their hours of business from strings to proper dates.

Cory is right about using MomentJs though. There are a lot unexpected things that can happen when working with time.

Comment: @martin the way the times are being parsed sets the date to 1/1/1900.
`var times = dealerSchedule[Object.keys(dealerSchedule)[now.getDay() - 1]].replace(/(\d\d\:\d\d)(AM|PM)/g, '1/1/1900 $1 $2').split(" - ");`